# Is it possible to put characters onto the image when it's being uploaded using peperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm using the gem called **paperclip**
Now user can upload the images with its function.
Is it possible to put the url of the web site onto this image uploaded when it's being saved into public dir?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with paperclip, instead you can try using ImageMagick : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php Using it once the image has been uploaded with paperclip should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with the help of ImageMagick

1. This [railscasts video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/374-image-manipulation) shows how to work with ImageMagick.
2. After that, you can take a look at [this document](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/) to see how you can annotate the image with text values.

Exmaple of annotation using ImageMagick

```
  convert dragon.gif   -background Khaki  label:'Faerie Dragon' \
          -gravity Center -append    anno_label.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. What if I just wanna put user_path(@user) in the bottom of the picture, how the rails command should be like?

Comment: @MKK so from the http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#gravity_text  you can do it by passing a string. and invoke it appropriately from rails to show the user details